# How do I add a new state to the Mantis workflow?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, bug-tracking, mantis

Mantis bugtracker have 7 states:

```
  New
  Feedback
  Acknowledged
  Confirmed
  Assigned
  Resolved
  Closed
```

I want to add a new state: `Suggested`. Where in the database do I add this new state?
Do I need to modify any PHP file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [manual entry on status values](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html/admin.customize.status.html) might help

Comment: Corrected the link to a version agnostic one